# How can I create linux debian package with multiple binary packages?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, debian

I am trying to package my c++ build targets. I have a binary that depends on a .so. I tried following

```
mkdir {pkg-name}-{pkg-version}
cd {pkg-name}-{pkg-version}
dh_make --indep --createorig
```

I am seeing following:

```
build@sjcvln1buildag1:~/my_build/ns1/cmake_build/stellus-dmn-1.0.0.212$ dh_make --indep --createorig
Email-Address       : build@unknown
License             : blank
Package Name        : stellus-dmn
Maintainer Name     : unknown
Version             : 1.0.0.212
Package Type        : indep
Date                : Fri, 11 Aug 2017 10:31:41 -0700
Are the details correct? [Y/n/q]
```

`Currently there is not top level Makefile. This mayrequire additional tuning
You already have a debian/ subdirectory in the sourcetree.`

How do I create a Makefile with dependencies? Any help is appreciated. I have a binary which depends on a .so for this package.`

Comment: You could start by reading some [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html) ...

Comment: @JesperJuhl I personally wasn't very happy with this doc. It is not the doc what you just find by google, do what it says, while you *understand what are you doing*, and everything is going finely. The learning curve of the debian package development is to me highly sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way for you would be splitting the package into two seperate packages.
Technically, you can (and for "real" debian packaging you 'should') use just one control file to generate both, but I guess its too complicated for the beginning. To keep it simple split it into:

a) libmypackage (containing the .so)

b) mypackage

In the control file of mypackage you'll set the dependencies to libmypackage, using the same version.